# How do IT teams set up a fleet of computers for new employees at the same time?

Tags: windows, installation, system, administration, system-administration

I've always wondered. In huge companies where the IT team has to set up hundreds of computers for new employees so that the computers have the same settings (e.g. join company domain, install antivirus, company programs, etc.), what methods do the IT team use to achieve this?

I'm sure their method is way more efficient than the only one I know, which is to boot up the computers and set them up by one.

Answer (score 0):

Alot of companies will have a custom image that they can just directly install onto the computers with the correct software and configurations, this is very much like what you would do if you set up a virtual machine.

Some have set up network infrastructures that allow them to just plug in an ethernet cable and issue a remote update which can reimage the computer in some instances.

In any case, it is going to be a fair bit of manual labour to get each computer and (at the very least) plug in an ethernet cable or add in a cd.